# C language: How to find the largest number created by digits from n using string

Tags: c, string, max, insertion-sort, function-definition

Question:Find the largest number and smallest created by digits from n (n<10 ^50) .
I have tried like the below but in some cases, it's wrong

For example:

Case 1: Input `2015` Output `5210`

Case 2: Input `47356359122` Output(Wrong answer)
Help me please, I don't know why I got the wrong answer!!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void max(char s[]) {
    int l = strlen(s);
    int i, key, j;
    for (i = 1; i < l; i++) {
        key = s[i];
        j = i - 1;
 
        while (j >= 0 && s[j] > key) {
            s[j + 1] = s[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        s[j + 1] = key;
    }
    s[l - 1] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", s);
}

int main() {
    char s[100];
    fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
    max(s);
}
```

Comment: Question: Find the largest number and smallest created by digits from n (n<10 ^50) . When I tested case 1: Input 2015 Output 5210 (Accepted) but case 2: Input 47356359122 Output (Wrong Answer).

Comment: How is “2015” true? 2015 is not the largest number that can be created from the digits 2, 0, 1, and 5. What is your program supposed to do? Is it supposed to read a string of digits and print the largest number that can be made from them? Or is it supposed to read a string of digits and print “true” if they already form the largest number that can be made from them and “false” otherwise?

Comment: @nanaboo, Please review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking a good and clear question is important. Please edit your question to contain the explanation you gave here. E.g., state that the input "2015" should result in the output "5210", but that your program produces [insert output]. Also explain the problem and your approach, this goes in a long way in determining exactly what goes wrong, and it shows that you've made an effort at solving the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is correct: sorting the digits in decreasing order produces the largest number from these digits.

Your implementation is flawed:

- you actually sort them in increasing order. You should change `while (j >= 0 && s[j] > key)` to

  ```
   while (j >= 0 && s[j] < key)
  ```
- the null terminator is set at the wrong position: you clear the last character in `s`. If the line read from `stdin` ends with a newline, this may erase it, unless the user typed a TAB character, but if the input consists only of digits, the last one will be removed. Change the code to:

  ```
   s[l - 1] = '\0';
  ```

Here is an alternative using counting sort:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void max_number(char s[]) {
    /* array to store the number of occurrences of each digit */
    int count[10] = { 0 }; 
    int i, d, c;
    /* enumerate all characters from the string, stop at the null terminator */
    for (i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        /* only count digits from '0' to '9' */
        if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') {
            /* increase the digit count for this digit */
            count[s[i] - '0']++;
        }
    }
    /* output the digits from highest to lowest */
    for (i = 0, d = 10; d --> 0;) {
        for (c = count[d]; c --> 0;)
            s[i++] = '0' + d;
    }
    if (i == 0) {
       /* there were no digits in the string: store a 0 */
       s[i++] = '0';
    }
    if (s[0] == '0') {
       /* there were only zeroes in the string: keep a single 0 */
       i = 1;
    }
    /* set the null terminator */
    s[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", s);
}

int main() {
    char s[100];
    if (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin))
        max_number(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

User [chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie) already provided an excellent general answer. Here is an addition with a simpler, slightly less efficient approach.

Observing that it is not necessary to actually store the result in a new string, you could also print the digits - high to low - as you find them. This program loops over the input string 10 times, first printing all `9`s, then all `8`s, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void max(char *str) {
    for (char digit = '9'; digit >= '0'; --digit) // Assume ASCII
        for (char *strCp = str; *strCp != '\0' ; ++strCp)
            if (*strCp == digit)
                putchar(digit);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void) {
    char s[100];
    if (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) != NULL)
        max(s);
}
```

Note:

- No `strlen` function is used, so the `string.h` header is no longer needed.
- Changed the `main` signature to `int main(void)`, which is suggested by the standard in case the parameters are not used.
- Checking the return value of `fgets`, so the program can handle empty input and input failure.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function should not output any message. It is the caller if the function that decides whether to output a message.

The function should return a modified string characters of which are sorted as digit in the descending order.

Your function can invoke undefined behavior when an empty string is passed to the function

```
void max(char s[]) {
    int l = strlen(s);
    int i, key, j;
    //...
    s[l - 1] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

because in this statement

```
s[l - 1] = '\0';
```

there is an attempt to access memory beyond the passed string. And in general the statement is wrong because the terminating zero must be present in the position `l` .

There is no need to set the terminating zero character `'\0'` because it is already present in the string. So the above statement is just redundant.

In fact you are trying to sort characters of the string using the insertion sort method in the ascending order due to the condition in this if statement.

```
while (j >= 0 && s[j] > key) {
```

In this case the new line character `'\n'` that is present in the string after calling the function `fgets` will be moved at the beginning of the string.

You have to sort the string in the descending order.

And the new line character `'\n'` should be removed from the string before calling the function.

The function can be declared and defined for example the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * max_number( char *s )
{
    if ( *s )
    {
        for ( char *p = s + 1; *p; ++p )
        {
            char c = *p;
            char *q = p;
            
            for ( ; q != s && *( q - 1 ) < c; --q )
            {
                *q = *( q - 1 );
            }
            
            if ( q != p ) *q = c;
        }
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[100];
    
    fgets( s, sizeof( s ), stdin );
    
    s[ strcspn( s, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
    
    puts( max_number( s ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

If to enter the number `47356359122`  using `fgets` then the program output will be

```
97655433221
```